# Ionic "SynatxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, ionic-framework, mean

Hello I have a small question: I created an application in the Ionic (localhost: 3000) and created also for the API MEAN (localhost: 4000), turn on the application Ionic in one terminal, the API for the second terminal, and here begins the problem namely, when you try to download data from the server using the GET request is performed correctly because it has the status of 200 but in response I get error:

> "SynatxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of
>   the JSON data"

I do not know how to fix data from the server sending ExpressJs:

```
app.get('/data', function(req, res) {
res.json({name: "kacper", age: 22})
});
```

Function in Ionic App:

```
$scope.getData = function(){
$http.get('http://localhost:4000/data').than(function(data){
console.log('Success: ' + data);
$scope.data = data;
}, function(err) {
console.log('Error: ' + err);
})
}
```

Always i get a error message but status is 200 or ionic app connects to the server.

body-parser configured:

> app.use (bodyParser.urlencoded ({extended: true})); app.use
>   (bodyParser.json ());

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

Just quote your keys of the json

```
res.json({"name": "kacper", "age": 22})
```

Also, if you are referencing to localhost, your client have to be in the same machine of the server, if you are testing in a real device, change to the server IP and check that it's accessible.

Finally, change your "than" for "then"

Comment: I changed it and continue the same error, version express: 4.8.8, version body-parser: 1.8.0

Comment: Are you sure that its the same error? unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data its a malformed JSON error, and this new one is well formed. Try your JSON in http://jsonlint.com/ and check errors